# how to make cluetips jquery show right side of <table>

Tags: jquery, ajax, position, cluetip

I have a table that load some datas from an ajax query..

I tried to make a cluetip (local, with arrows) on it..

this is my cluetip options:

```
$('.load-local').cluetip({
        sticky: true,
        arrows: true,
        showTitle: false,
        mouseOutClose: true,
        delayedClose: 400,
        local: true,
        hideLocal: true,
        width: 170
    });
```

I put it on a certain `<td>` (under 'Details' section)..

So that when user hover to its `<td>` a cluetip will showing on the right side like I want..

I attached a preview of it:

[image: right side]

Then, I decided to modified it to be more effective for user..

So if user hover to a `<tr>`, the cluetip will showing..

But, when I put cluetip class and rel attribute on this `<tr>`, the cluetip is showing on the left side..

I attached a preview of it:

[image: left side]

**I want: when user hover to the `<tr>` the cluetip will show on right side (like I did on the `<td>`)..**

How can I make it?

I have already tried with jquery to trigger the `<td>` when `mouseover` the `<tr>`, but still failed..

Do you have any idea about it?

Thank You Very Much..

Answer (score 0):

Have you done..

```
$('.load-local td').cluetip({
        sticky: true,
        arrows: true,
        showTitle: false,
        mouseOutClose: true,
        delayedClose: 400,
        local: true,
        hideLocal: true,
        width: 170
    });
```

Try and select the child td elements of tr.

Comment: I have tried it, still can't.. Btw what do you mean by 'select the child elements of'? Thanks..

Comment: I meant select $('tr td') like above but if you've done that then not sure what to suggest.